# SharePoint list How to restrict input value format

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a column with name Secure in my SharePoint list. And I want to set validation in that column as below mentioned conditions. and if any user not entered in that format than , he will not able to save the form.

Condition :-

1. it should contain total 12 characters
2. first four character should be Alphabet (i.e. A to Z)
3. next 4 characters should be any number between 0 to 9
4. next 4 character should follow DDMM format (i.e. DD should allow maximum value 31/30/29/28 as per month and MM should between 01 to 12)

Answer (score 0):

Because there is no clear year information, it is impossible to tell whether February is 28 or 29 days.

However, you could create three columns to achieve your plan:

**Please the following steps:**

1. Column1: Test[Single line of text]

In the Test field, you must to enter 8 characters:

- The first 4 characters are uppercase letters
- The last 4 characters are numbers from 0 to 9

Formula:

```
=AND(LEN(Test)=8,CODE(MID(Test,1,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,1,1))<91,CODE(MID(Test,2,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,2,1))<91,CODE(MID(Test,3,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,3,1))<91,CODE(MID(Test,4,1))>64,CODE(MID(Test,4,1))<91,CODE(MID(Test,5,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,5,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,6,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,6,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,7,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,7,1))<58,CODE(MID(Test,8,1))>47,CODE(MID(Test,8,1))<58)
```

[image: Test]

2. Column2: Date[Date and Time]

[image: Date]

3. Column3:IDs[Calculated]

The IDs field automatically generates **a unique identifier** based on the value of the Test field and the Date field, without your manual operation.

Formula:

```
=Test&TEXT(Date,"ddmm")
```

[image: IDs]

[image: Error vs Success]

Have a nice day!